Hankel transform of $f(r)=\mathrm{erfc}(r)J_{1}(r)/r$
I encountered a Hankel transform dealing with the Ewald method.
The Hankel transform of zero order is defined as
$$F(k)=\int_{0}^{\infty}f(r)J_{0}(kr)\,r\,dr,$$
where $J_{0}$ is the Bessel function of the first kind of zero order.
I know that the Hankel transform of $\mathrm{erfc}(r)/r$ is $\mathrm{erf}(k/2)/k$, but I have no idea about the following one,
$$f(r)=\mathrm{erfc}(r)J_{1}(r)/r,$$
where $\mathrm{erfc}$ is the complementary error function and $J_{1}$ is the Bessel function of the first kind of first order.
Could someone help? Thank you!

It would seem that expanding the error function into a series and then evaluating the Hankel transform would lead to a series form that could be evaluated, or at least placed into a form of a known function.

@MariuszIwaniuk, thanks for answering, could you elaborate more on how you got this double series?

Expressed by double infinte series: $$\text{HankelTransform}\left[\frac{J_1(r) \text{erfc}(r)}{r},r,k\right]=\frac{1}{8} \sum {m=0}^{\infty } \sum {n=0}^{\infty }
\frac{\left(\left(\frac{3}{2}\right){m+n} (1){m+n}\right) \left(\left(-\frac{k^2}{4}\right)^n \left(-\frac{1}{4}\right)^m\right)}{\left((2)_{m+n} (2)_m
(1)_n\right) (n! m!)}$$Probably series can be expressed by Kampé de Fériet Function or Lauricella Functions

Too much to write here. I performed 100% of the calculations in Mathematica. I checked numerically that my solution was accurate.

Solution by  Kampé de Fériet function: $$\frac{1}{8},
\mathrm{F}^{2:0;0}_{1:1;1}
\Bigg(
\begin{matrix}
\frac{3}{2},1 &:& -&;- & \
2&:&2&;1&
\end{matrix}
\Bigg|
\frac{-1}{4},-\frac{k^2}{4}
\Bigg)
$$

@MariuszIwaniuk, thanks for answering! would you mind sharing the code of Mathematica which generates the series answer? thank you!
